# How can the proof of a local theorem on a manifold involving a map with a fixed point and a differential be reduced to the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Case in point: the Hartman-Grobman theorem (for maps). In the book "Geometric Theory of Dynamical Systems: An Introduction" by Palis and De Melo, the theorem is stated as follows (on page 60).

> **Theorem**. Let $f \in \mathrm{Diff}^r(M)$ and let $p \in M$ be a hyperbolic fixed point of $f$. Let $A = Df_p : TM_p \to TM_p$. Then there exist neighborhoods $V(p) \subset M$ and $U(0) \subset TM_p$ and a homeomorphism $h: U \to V$ such that $$hA = fh.$$
>
> **Remark.** As this is a local problem we can, by using a local chart, suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a diffeomorphism with $0$ as a hyperbolic fixed point.

I don't see why the remark is true. I understand that we can use a local chart to go from $f: M \to M$ to $g: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Namely, $g = \phi f \phi^{-1}$ for a chart $\phi: W(p) \to \mathbb{R}^m$ will do and $\phi(p) = 0$ is easy to arrange. But how are $Df_p$ and $Dg_0$ related?

Comment: By conjugation with $D \phi_0$. We have something like $Dg_0 = D \phi_{0} \circ Df_p \circ (D\phi_{0})^{-1}$. Now note that hyperbolicity for a fixed point is a property of the spectrum (how would this be phrased?). How are the spectra of conjugate linear maps related?

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say a dynamical system is a $C^r$-diffeomorphism $f: M \to M$ acting on a $C^r$-manifold $M$.

**Lemma.**
Suppose the Hartman-Grobman theorem holds for real dynamical systems (i.e. for $M = \mathbb{R}^n$). Then it holds for all dynamical systems.

**Proof.**
Let $f : M \to M$ be a dynamical system with a hyperbolic fixed point $p \in M$.
Choose a single chart $\phi : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $U \subset M$ is an open neighborhood of $p$, such that $\phi(p) = 0$.
Then $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $g = \phi f \phi^{-1}$ is a real dynamical system with $g(0) = 0$.
Hence by the Hartman-Grobman theorem for real dynamical systems, there exists a homeomorphism $H: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$g = H^{-1}Dg_0H.$$
But by the chain rule from differential geometry, $$Dg_0 = D\phi_p Df_p D\phi_0^{-1},$$ and since conjugate linear maps have the same eigenvalues, the origin is a hyperbolic fixed point of $g$.
From the two preceding equations and $f = \phi^{-1}g\phi$ we can construct a homeomorphism $h : M \to T_pM$ such that $f = h^{-1}Df_0h$.
Namely $h = D\phi_0^{-1}H\phi$ will do, recalling from differential geometry that $D\phi_0^{-1} = (D\phi_p)^{-1}$.

Comment: You could also use the application exponential (and the fact that it identifies not closed geodesics and geodesic lines and identifies with closed circles). But your solution is much simpler.

Comment: @E. How would that work? Would you use the exponential map $\exp: T_pM \to M$ to prove the Hartman-Grobman theorem itself? If I understand correctly then you would also need a connection on $M$.